# Removing multiple spaces and trailing spaces using gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How can I remove multiple spaces and trailing spaces using only 1 gsub? I already made this function `trim <- function(x) gsub(' {2,}',' ',gsub('^ *| *$','',x))`, but i'm trying to rewrite it with only 1 gsub.

Actually, I want lean how to match something based in what is after/before it with gsub. In this example I need to match all spaces that are preceeded by a single space, and replace them by ''

Comment: Can you rephrase and clarify your last statement about matching all spaces that are preceded by a single space?  Do you mean you want to reduce any multiple number of spaces down to a single space?

Comment: @Dinre, yes, I want reduce all multiple spaces to a single one. As you can see, the 1st gsub() (the 'outside' one) do exactlly this, but I want use only 1 gsub(), and that's why I asked a way to remove all spaces preceded by another space (to use the same gsub() used to remove trailing spaces)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind to see if the current space is preceded by a space:

```
^ *|(?<= ) | *$
```

See it here in action: http://regex101.com/r/bJ1mU0

Comment: For completeness (my answer edit was rejected), here's the full function: 
`trim <- function(x) return(gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", x, perl=T))`

Comment: please give one good reason why you are not answering this question in the context of r. all regex flavors are _not_ the same; you need to tailor your answer in the context of that which it is asked. @MaxGhenis did all the work for you, just add it to your answer which is not useful as written

Comment: It looks like @rawr's edit including my function was approved, then Joseph Silber re-edited it to remove it. What gives? Please add a separate question if you want to provide a general regex solution, otherwise respect OP's R tag and provide an R solution.