# Removing multiple commas and trailing commas using gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

This question is very similar to [Removing multiple spaces and trailing spaces using gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14737266/1840471), except that I'd like to apply it to commas instead of spaces.

For example, I'd like a function `TrimCommas` to turn `x` into `y`:

```
x <- c("a,b,c", ",a,b,,c", ",,,a,,,b,c,,,")
# y <- TrimCommas(x) # presumably
y <- c("a,b,c", "a,b,c", "a,b,c")
```

The solution for spaces was `gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", x, perl=T)`, so I'm hoping comparing the solution for this will help explain some regex fundamentals as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Isn't the solution pretty similar?

```
x <- c("a,b,c", ",a,b,,c", ",,,a,,,b,c,,,")
gsub("^,*|(?<=,),|,*$", "", x, perl=T)
# [1] "a,b,c" "a,b,c" "a,b,c"
```

There are three parts to the regex `^,*|(?<=,),|,*$`:

- `^,*` -- this matches 0 or more commas at the beginning of the string
- `(?<=,),` -- this is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to see if there a comma behind a comma, so it matches `,` in `,,`
- `,*$` -- this matches 0 or more commas at the end of the string

As you can see all of the above are substituted with nothing.

You can make this generic to any character (`" "`, `","`, etc.) with this function:

```
TrimMult <- function(x, char=" ") {
  return(gsub(paste0("^", char, "*|(?<=", char, ")", char, "|", char, "*$"),
              "", x, perl=T))
}
```

Comment: +1. Just wondering if I had to need that the positive look behind part was needed to be replaced by "1,", how would I do that??

Comment: @Shambho Could you give example input & output?

Comment: input: `x <- c("a,b,c", ",a,b,,c", ",,,a,,,b,c,,,")`, and output 
`o <- c("a,b,c", ",a,b,1,c", "a,1,b,c")`

Comment: @Shambho This is a rather different example.  Could you [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead?

Comment: Thanks, @devnull, especially for the explanation of the three components.

Comment: @MaxGhenis And to you for adding the function!