# R inserts 1 additional obs. and 1 additional var. when reading csv

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, upload, rows

When uploading my CSV-file to r, a row as well as a column is added to the data frame, although these rows are empty in the CSV-file. The data frame should have 2005 obs. and 49 variables. But when uploading, it results in a data frame with 2006 obs. and 50 variables. Also, some of the fields are filled with NA's by r after the upload.

This is the code I'm using for uploading the file into r:

`Dev_REITs_MTBV <- read.csv2("Developed_REITS_MTBV.csv", na="NA")`

Here's the csv-file:

https://gofile.io/d/7jzEub

Code running before upload:

```
pkgs <- c("readxl","akima","rgl","scatterplot3d","car","MASS","ISLR","stargazer","urca","rpart","ggplot2","e1071","randomForest",
          "quantreg","mgcv","gamlss","rlang","gplots","psych","ggridges","viridis","caTools","caret","forecast", "shape", "diagram", 
          "writexl", "openxlsx", "maptools", "ggridges", "calibrate", "modelr", "XLConnect")
for (pkg in pkgs) {if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }}
lapply(pkgs, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Here are pictures of my input CSV rows and columns as well as the resulting data frame:

[Empty row CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsW7K.jpg)

[Empty column CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHhBN.jpg)

[Unwanted data frame row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Tuz.jpg)

[Unwanted data frame column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKdyM.jpg)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Hi Connor! It's really difficult to help you like this. Open your CSV with a text reader (like notepad or notepad++, not with Excel!) and copy here the first two lines and last two lines. From there we can dig into the problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Edo.
I've added the csv file to the original question.

Comment: I run your code with your data and I have no problem. I get a data frame with 2305 rows and 49 columns. Try to clean your environment with `rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))` and restart R with the combination `CTRL + SHIFT + F10` (on Windows)

Comment: For future reference, sharing a csv this way is not a best practise. You should have copied 4 lines into your question as I suggested you.

Comment: @ConnorUhl Also for me `Dev_REITs_MTBV <- read.csv2("https://srv-file8.gofile.io/downloadStore/srv-store4/7jzEub/Developed_REITS_MTBV.csv")` is working fine without a problem. So your problem described in your question is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and sorry for not following best practise. I'm pretty new here ;)
Cleaning my environment and restarting hasn't helped, unfortunately.

Could it have anything to do with the packages I installed beforehand?
I've included the code running in front of the upload to the original question.

Comment: @ConnorUhl Yes, that could be. Try (from a clear R-session) first read the data and then load the packages (do you really need so much packages?).

Comment: Still didn't help, unfortunately!
Yes I do! I've got quite a lot of plotting ahead of me.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `read_csv()` from the tidyverse? without the actual file this might be hard to troubleshoot, but just trying another package might just solve it. you could also try `fread()` from the data.table package

EDIT/ADDED Later:

Your data is quite messy (having ',' instead of '.' as decimal separators and ';' and column separators, having a whole bunch of trailing commas in your last column and having numbers (years) as variable names. However, this code should fix it:

```
library(tidyverse) # you need dplyr 1.0.0 or later

# load data
dataset <- read_delim("Developed_REITS_MTBV.csv", delim = ";") %>%
  # rename final column
  rename(`2019` = `2019,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`) %>%
  # delete all trailing commas in last column (but not the first one)
  mutate(`2019` = gsub("^,*|(?<=,),|,*$", "", `2019`, perl = T)) %>%
  # name the year columns numeric after switching the commas to points
  mutate(across(c(`1980`:`2019`), ~as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", .))))
```

part of the code comes from: [Removing multiple commas and trailing commas using gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274035/removing-multiple-commas-and-trailing-commas-using-gsub)

Comment: whoever downvoted this answer should have explained why... however, I suppose the problem is that this is more of a comment rather than a real answer to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help L Smeets.
I've added the CSV-file to the original question.

Comment: Ok I have now added a real answer