# How to remove an unnamed element from a single item list?

Tags: r, string, list

This may sound a very beginner's question and very well it could also be a very basic and stupid question, but somehow I am having headache in doing it.

Let's suppose I have a single item list

```
v <- as.list("1, 2, 3,")

v
[[1]]
[1] "1, 2, 3,"
```

Now I want to split all of its items as separate items

```
v2 <- lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ","), trimws)
v2
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3" ""
```

Now I want to remove this `""` from the first and only item of this list without using `[]`?

Comment: `[]` is used (as per my understanding and I may be wrong) when I know the number/position of element in a list.  In this case I am not really aware of its position?

Comment: You coudl still use [] with a dynamic vector of elements to delete - see my solution below.

Comment: *Why* do you have a single item `list` and not just a character vector?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, Thanks for asking and taking interest.  There is no specific reason for doing so in lists except that I wanted to learn things doing the `lists` way in R instead of always doing it in `vectors`.  I somehow feel that full potential of R can be unleashed by utilising the lists.  Please have a look on my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65388891/r-how-to-accumulate-values-in-a-list-column-based-on-multiple-criteria) on which I am still working.  During the past few months, I have found SO the best way to self learn.

Comment: @AnilGoyal, Agreed--SO is a great way to self-learn. Part of the reason for asking is to get to better understand the scope of the problem being explored (for instance, why try to solve this without using `[]` and why you'd be starting with a single-item list). I think, for example, that understanding why jay.sf's `strsplit` works is the important lesson in his answer (and it's documented in `?strsplit`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `nzchar`.

```
lapply(v2, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Or use `base::strsplit` in the first place which appears to be more sophisticated.

```
lapply(strsplit(v[[1]], ","), trimws)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: Any reason for `x[nchar(x) > 0]` and not the faster `x[nzchar(x)]`?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 You're absolutely right, updated thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Filter` with `nchar`

```
v2 <- lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ",\\s?"), Filter, f = nchar)
```

which gives

```
> v2
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is also `setdiff` to remove the `""`

```
lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ",\\s*"), setdiff, "")
#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether you have a `list` with just one item or more, I'd probably do something like:

```
str_split(gsub("^,|,$|\\s+", "", v), ",")
```

Or better yet:

```
strsplit(gsub("^,|,$|\\s+", "", v), ",", TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

(Or, maybe even `strsplit(gsub("^,|,$|\\s", "", gsub(", ,", ",", v, fixed = TRUE)), ",", TRUE)` depending on your actual data.)

---

Here's an example with a `list` with multiple elements as opposed to a `list` with just one element.

```
v <- rep(v, 2500)
```

I've put the other answers into functions, modifying as appropriate to make them work on multiple `list` elements. Here are the functions I've tested:

```
fun_a5a <- function() str_split(gsub("^,|,$|\\s+", "", v), ",")
fun_a5b <- function() strsplit(gsub("^,|,$|\\s+", "", v), ",", TRUE)

fun_ak <- function() lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ",\\s*"), setdiff, "")

fun_des <- function() {
  v2 <- lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ","), trimws)
  lapply(v2, function(x) x[x != ""])
}

fun_hfa <- function() Map(function(x){trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))}, v)
fun_hfb <- function() sapply(v, strsplit, ",\\s*")

fun_jay <- function() lapply(unlist(lapply(v, strsplit, ","), recursive = FALSE), trimws)

fun_tica <- function() lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ",\\s?"), Filter, f = nchar)
fun_ticb <- function() lapply(str_split(v, pattern = ",\\s?"), Filter, f = nzchar)
```

Here are the results:

```
bench::mark(fun_a5a(), fun_a5b(), 
            fun_ak(), 
            fun_des(), 
            fun_hfa(), fun_hfb(), 
            fun_jay(),
            fun_tica(), fun_ticb())
# # A tibble: 9 x 13
#   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
#   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
# 1 fun_a5a()   2.47ms  2.63ms     372.     58.7KB     2.04   183     1    491.4ms <list…
# 2 fun_a5b()   1.85ms   1.9ms     517.     58.7KB     2.03   255     1    493.4ms <list…
# 3 fun_ak()   14.17ms 14.85ms      66.8    58.7KB    44.5     15    10    224.5ms <list…
# 4 fun_des()  62.86ms 62.86ms      15.9    78.3KB   111.       1     7     62.9ms <list…
# 5 fun_hfa()  82.17ms 82.17ms      12.2    19.6KB    73.0      1     6     82.2ms <list…
# 6 fun_hfb()  13.36ms 13.59ms      72.9    90.8KB     9.11    32     4    438.9ms <list…
# 7 fun_jay()   71.3ms  71.3ms      14.0    58.7KB    84.2      1     6     71.3ms <list…
# 8 fun_tica() 21.97ms  22.2ms      44.5    58.7KB    66.8      8    12    179.7ms <list…
# 9 fun_ticb() 13.12ms 13.59ms      73.5    58.7KB    44.1     20    12    272.2ms <list…
# # … with 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>

ggplot::autoplot(.Last.value)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more ugly version (just as an additional idea, but the solution from jay.sf seems to be preferable):

Based on your v2 input:

```
delete <- which(v2[[1]] == "")

v2[[1]] <- v2[[1]][-delete]

# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: I'd use `nzchar` instead. Also, you shouldn't need to calculate the indices with `which` since you are already creating a logical vector that you can use to subset.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map()`:

```
Map(function(x){trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))}, v)
```

Using `sapply()`:

```
sapply(v, strsplit, ",\\s*")
```

Comment: Interesting! UPVOTED. please explain the purpose of regex `",|, "` here

Comment: @AnilGoyal "1, 2, " should be split on ", " instead of ",", this prevents having to also call the `trimws()` function.