# How to remove a list of strings in a list

Tags: r

I hope to remove strings from a list if they appeared in another list.

For instance,

```
original <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
to.remove <- c ("c","a")
```

And I am expecting to get

```
"b", "d", "e"
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: But the example you have given @karyn-h is not a list. Lists may behave slightly different from a vector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408309/how-to-remove-an-unnamed-element-from-a-single-item-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setdiff` does this:

```
setdiff(original, to.remove)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
original[!(original %in% to.remove)]

# [1] "b" "d" "e"
```